# Cannot point domain name to Windows Azure Website

Tags: azure, dns, azure-storage, cname, azure-web-app-service

I signed up for an As-You-Go account with Windows Azure, and created an SQL DB and setup 'Websites'. I then successfully deployed my website to my Azure account and read a *bunch* of articles online that basically said I need to CNAME my domain name to my Windows Azure Websites URL.

So I did that:

[image]

I then stumbled upon another article that said "for 'Websites' you need to scale the server to 'Reserved' mode."

I did that too:

[image]

But it hasn't worked.

I am getting a 404 on my homepage which is hosted on my previous hosting company's server, *even though I've set it up to point to Azure's servers.*

Can anyone please help shed some light on this? Am I doing something wrong?
As you can see, it's been about 72 hours already, and given the information above, to me, it suggest that it still hasn't propagated yet. Is this the case?

Comment: Some info here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't see how any of that could be of help, as I've already performed all steps mentioned in that link, as I've mentioned in the question. Which part were you referring to?

Comment: That is why it was only a comment. It just validated what you had stated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Configure page, you also need to enter your custom hostname:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I just updated my custom hostname to include my address. It works. :D