# Web Matrix 2 - Downloading and installing publish settings

Tags: node.js, azure, webmatrix

I am an azure customer, however when I log into the azure portal I see the old azure portal interface without anyway of upgrading or updating it.  I want to download my publish settings to use in webmatrix to upload node.js website.

How do I get the publish settings for my azure website using the old portal interface?

I have tried using powershell cmdlet Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile however when I instructed webmatrix to use the downloaded publish settings file I got an error from webmatrix saying there was an error with the publish settings file.

Is there any other way to upload my webmatrix node.js website to my windows azure website ?

Answer (score 0):

To access the new (preview) portal you have to use https://manage.windowsazure.com/ instead of https://windows.azure.com/. This will allow you to access your web sites and download the publish profile (in the dashboard of your website, under **quick glance**).

Comment: thanks sandrino, I am in the dashboard but I dont see the quick glance option anywhere?

I have a cloud service and storage service running, all I see is a message saying 'you have not deployed anything to the production environment'. Is it still possible to download the publish settings?

Comment: You'll need to go under Web Sites, not Cloud Services. In order to get the Web Sites menu you'll need to sign up for the preview feature: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/preview/

Comment: ok well i can't do that as I only have one credit card that I signed up with for my original account.  Now how do I get access to my current azure websites publish settings if the old portal and new portal won't give them to me?

Comment: You can't. You'll need to activate the Web Sites feature first, access the new portal, create a new web site and download the publish profile for that site.

Comment: can i set it up using the ftp option in webmatrix?  Where do I get the windows azure cloud service ftp details from ?

Comment: The FTP details are also in the Web Sites dashboard for a specific site (under quick glance). But to access this you'll need to activate the feature, access the new portal and create a new web site first..

Comment: ok thanks sandrino, i think some more explaining by microsoft about cloud service and website service etc would help.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Services are different than Windows Azure Web Sites.  At the bottom of the new po[image]rtal there will be a "+ New" button, when you click it you should get the attached view.  That is where you create a website.  It will then have a location to download publish settings from the dashboard.  That is the publish setting which can be imported into WebMatrix to deploy your node.js site to Azure.  Hope this helps.

-Vishal R. Joshi | http://vishalrjoshi.com | @vishalrjoshi