# Difference Between Azure Web Site and Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, sql-server-2008-r2, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I'm about to migrate several separate ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms applications to Azure. Several are apps using SQL Server 2008. I'm seeing "conflicting" tutorials for this:

[Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site and SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/)

vs

[Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Cloud Service and SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/)

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role) goes some way towards explaining this. However, there have been several changes to Azure in recent months and I'm not sure how up to date the information is.

I want as simple a migration process as possible because of the number of sites I have to migrate. Is there a situation where I would *have to* use the Cloud Service route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from what the linked-to answer provides: You *have to* go the Cloud Service route if there are apps you need to install (e.g. an MSI, COM object, etc.). There's simply no facility to do this with Web Sites. In Web Sites, you cannot alter the VM instance at all. With Cloud Services, you have lots of flexibility to install software, alter IIS behavior, pretty much anything you need to do (as long as the installs can be automated).

Comment: So Cloud Service is basically a VM? If this is the case, would I be looking at licensing fees?

Comment: No licensing fees: you pay usage per hour. You'd only pay licensing for software you needed to purchase that you're installing. Cloud Service is not just a VM though: The host OS is completely managed for you, as is the Guest OS. In other words, you never have to install Windows patches; that's completely taken care of. The VM boots and then loads your software. For full VM customization (where there's no OS automation), you'd need to work with Virtual Machines, yet another feature of Azure.

Comment: Most of the Web apps involved are e-commerce stores. ASP.NET session state us used - does this present any problems if I go the simple Web site route?

Answer (score 4):

One point which can be very valuable if you consider migration of ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms applications - Microsoft Azure Websites do no support SSL for custom domains yet. That might be a blocker for your migration work to the Websites service.

Note that Windows Azure is very dynamic environment with great number of new features coming every new release. **In order to be up-to-date I would suggest following [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) to find out about new features and their release dates**.

**EDIT**

Windows Azure Website supports SSL for custom domains now. SSL Certificates and SSL bindings can be configured in **Configure** tab.

[image: Windows Azure SSL Support]

You can also read more about SSL configuration for Azure Website at [Configuring an SSL certificate for a Windows Azure web site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/).

Comment: Sadly I have the same issue with Azure Websites. I updated my answer with ScottGu's blog link. You can find out more on new features from there.

Comment: So for SSL-enabled sites, I would currently have to go the Cloud Service route?

Comment: @IrishChieftain, yes, at this moment it seems to be the only option. Or if you do not require custom domain names for your sites, default DNS for Azure websites could be used as *.azurewebsites.net have SSL support (default Microsoft one).

Comment: Update: Websites with .Net 4.5 do support SSL