# ?Can I host a MVC3 website on an Azure Web Site or I need to create a Cloud Service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-web-app-service

Can I host a MVC3 website on an Azure Web Site ?

I try to deploy an MVC3 website to Azure Web Sites (in preview).
If I leave the web.config file I got an error.
If I remove the web.config file,  like I did with a normal ASP.net website,  then I got other errors that seems related to MVC3.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're asking two questions: one on Web Sites vs. Cloud Services (and you can use either), and one on some web.config issue (which you need to be more specific about; as it stands, it's very open-ended and hard to answer, such as "other errors that seems related to MVC3" - you really should be showing some errors and explain what, exactly you tried.

Comment: Regarding the former (Web Sites vs. Cloud Services), I gave a fairly comprehensive answer to that question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941526/272109). You should look at that to see the differences and make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following this tutorial.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/

It seems that if you if you have some additional configuration, you need the SDK.

To publish plain aspx websites, you dont need the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of running an MVC website in Azure websites, I found this: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/