# Running batch process in Windows Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

Deploying apps to [Windows Azure Websites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/) feels incredibly more convenient compared to the initial WebRole option. Being able to push through Git, and get the app restarted in ~20s is a massive improvement over the 15min role redeploy.

Thus, I am considering using this option for what used to be hosted in WorkerRole as well. Indeed, it's possible to allocate a full VM to run *WA website*.

Are there any *gotcha* to be aware of when attempting this? Obviously, as the name suggests, *WA websites* are not intended for backoffice processing.

Answer (score 1):

In an upcoming feature for Windows Azure Websites, the scenario you're referring to will be supported:
http://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs

The following will allow you to have 2 types of processes to run aside your website:

1. Triggered - Start your process on a scheduled (or manual) basis.
2. Continuous - Your process will always be on (if it goes, it brings it back up).

Regarding the differences between Azure Webrole and Azure Website, there's a different question:
[What is the difference between an Azure Web Site and an Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Services gives you two different environments: staging and production. You can also use Continous deployment with Git, Tfs, Codeplex, Dropbox too. But if you don't need this two environments, you can go with websites.

Using a Virtual Machine, you'll be responsible for the operating system, runtime, data and also your app (obviously). Just be aware that you'll have to apply the service packs / security packs by yourself. If your app doesn't use 3rd party components I don't see a reason to use a VM for that.