# What kind of application can I deploy to Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I can't find answer for this simple question: What kind of application can I deploy to Windows Azure?

Can I upload only ASP .NET apps or can I upload:

1. Windows Forms Applicaton
2. Windows Presentation Foundation Application (WPF)
3. Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary of the sorts of applications you can host on Azure:

#### Platform as a service

- Azure Websites

  - Most existing / new Microsoft-stack (IIS-hosted) web applications (ASP.Net MVC, Web API, Web Forms, etc.)
  - A bunch of existing / new web applications written in other popular languages (Java, PHP, Node.js or Python)
- Azure Cloud Services

  - Newer Microsoft-stack (IIS-hosted) web applications similar to above, but with some additional functionality / overheads ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role) will give you a good comparison of the two)
  - New web (IIS-hosted) applications designed to take advantage of Azure hosting (for example separating front-end and back-end concerns using web and worker roles, again covered in the linked answer)

#### Infrastructure as a Service (VMs)

- Anything that you might host in a VM in another data centre / on another cloud service provider--usually legacy web applications / services, or those where the owner avoid tying their application code to a particular vendor by building on top of their PaaS

You'll notice that these are all basically webby, which excludes the likes of WinForms, WPF apps, and any other applications that are designed to run for users on their local machines.  To directly answer your question:

1. ASP.Net applications--yes, you can host these on Azure
2. WinForms applications--no, you can't host these on Azure
3. WPF applications--no, you can't host these on Azure
4. Other applications--if they're web-based and fall within the broad descriptions above, then there's a decent chance you'll be able to host them on Azure, but it really depends on the nature of the application

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms and WPF applications typically comprise of a rich client application as well as dependencies on backend services and databases. Windows Azure provides a great host for the backend services and databases - and you can learn more about this [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) - especially in the compute section. There is also a lot more you can do - so just take a look at the other links for more information.

Enjoy!

Jason

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: The answer is offtopic.