# Can Azure webjob install Java JRE?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I want to install Java JRE as part of my webjob. It actually checks whether JRE is installed or not. If not it download it from azure blob and try to install it. 
Since during runtime, webjobs binaries are copied in a temp folder before running the job, whether it is possible to perform this action of installing JRE or not? Or i need to have some special permission for the webjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You cannot do that. You cannot run installer from a Web Job. Web Jobs are executed in the context of a Website, in the security context of your Website (which is very restricted and sandboxed).

If you want to customize the OS, you have to chose the PaaS offering (Microsoft Azure Cloud Services) - Web Role or Worker Role. For some detailed information in differences between Web Sites and Web Roles, check out [the detailed answer of this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role).

Once you chose Cloud Services, you can [run StartUp tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx) to install anything on the OS. More on [Startup Tasks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg456327.aspx).

SInce you are interested in running Java on Azure, [here is your point of start](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/). And [here is the Azure Java SDK and Eclipse Plugin](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-download-windows/).

Comment: I take it this is the reason I'm getting the following exception when trying to run the Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB) out-of-process host application: *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Only users with administrative privileges, users in the Performance Log Users group, and services running as LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService can control event tracing sessions. To grant a restricted user the ability to control trace sessions, add them to the Performance Log Users group*? Any plans to allow control over WebJob permissions that you know of?