# Can I run a Node/ExpressJS application on Azure App Service or do I have to use Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have found examples of running a simple Node only application under an Azure App Service.  But for ExpressJS the examples I've found have all used an Azure Cloud Service.  New to Azure and just trying to figure out what I should be using.

Simple NodeJS to Azure App Service
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/

Simple ExpressJS to Azure Cloud Service
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-express-app/

Comment: Just curious what led you to believe you couldn't run an express app via web app. And there's no simple answer to which you should use.  You might want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941526/272109) I posted, enumerating several differences.

Comment: @DavidMakogon When I try to create a "Web App" in azure, I'm directed to App Services.

Comment: App Services is the umbrella service stack which includes Web App (and Mobile App, and API App, etc.).

Comment: What lead me to believe I couldn't were the tutorials I posted above and I also tried to deploy my node/express app via the App Service without success.

Am I able to run Node & Express in an App Service?  If so, I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no issue running an ExpressJS app in an app service. You just need to properly install your node packages during local dev, then push your app + related packages to your web app (via git, dropbox, or any of the other version control providers).

There are specific differences between web apps and cloud services (web/worker role instances) which I call out in a different answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10941526/272109)), such as web apps being restricted to just ports 80 and 443.

You'll also need to properly manage the version of node your app is using, as it might not match up with the default nodejs version installed in Web Apps.

Comment: Thank you.  I believe you have pointed out my mistake from the last time I tried this.  I did not push the packages I was using and attempted to perform an NPM install once it was deployed.  I will try again with the App Service.