# Compare azure app service (web) features with IIS

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

Currently I have a website running on IIS V8.5 and have set up a test Web App Service on Azure, published to it, and it runs fine. Strategically I want to move many websites to Azure.

However I cannot find any documentation detailing a comparison of features between IIS and Azure's Web App - especially the 'no such feature' ones.

I have seen many SQL Server vs Azure's SQL V12 features comparisons but none for website serving - maybe I'm searching with wrong keywords?

I just don't want to come across the "It won't do what!!! But that's so important!!!" scenario down the track.

**EDIT**

I want to focus only on running a website using Web App Service versus running a website on an IIS whose settings I can control.

So when I run a website on my IIS (I am looking at the main panel of my website right now) and there are 3 sections AS.NET, IIS, Management, and each has a number of the usual icons. By clicking on any of them I am presented with a number of settings that I can control.

What I would like to know is which settings are not available to me when I use Web App Service.

Especially the gotchas. There's always gotchas!

Comment: While it's not exactly the same, I gave a fairly thorough rundown of Web Apps (formerly web sites) vs Web Roles, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941526/272109). Considering Web Roles are just stateless Windows Server VMs (with specialized code-packaging plus bootstrap code), the comparison should help when comparing to Virtual Machines as well.

Comment: Thanks David - unfortunately because of the very fast changing nature of Azure it's very hard to determine what is current in your post.

Answer (score 3):

We are also working on something similar to what you have now. I understand you would like to explore and understand the following to know if Azure can handle your workloads.

1. Your current WebServer might be of X GB RAM and Y CPU Processor Cores. you would like to understand similar configuration on Azure?. Answer - You need to explore **Azure app Service Plans.**. It's the one which tells you the capacity. Please have a look at different App Service Plans to better understand about the capacity related stuff.
2. Your current environment might have Load Balancing. You would like to understand similar stuff on Azure? Answer - Azure App Service Plans have built Load Balancers for few of the Plans. Please have a look and decide which plan you would like to go for.
3. Your current WebServer might have some third party installations. You would like to understand if something of such stuff is really possible in Azure? Answer - No, It's not possible in App Services. You might have to go for either Cloud Services or Virtual Machine depending on the third party software.

Thanks,
Prawin

Answer (score 0):

As David said, Azure provide Web app, Web Role & Virtual Machine to host our website. When move the site to Azure, the first thing we need to consider is which one we need to use. Here is an article compare the differences: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/. Please read this article, then choose the best one for you. As I know, Azure web app is very easy to use. However we have no permission to install any IIS components. We can [remote to Azure Web App IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-microsoft-azure-web-sites/) to see the detailed difference with your local IIS. If some features don't meet your requirement, please consider [use Azure VM instead](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-web-app-visual-studio/).

Comment: Thanks Jambor - your first link is good but does not answer my question specifically. I will edit it to possibly make clearer what I am after.