# What are Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am a little confused in Azure web roles. Does they exists now as when I search in azure portal for "web roles" it gives me an option of "cloud services(classic)". Does it means that it existed before and now its terminated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course it exists. It gives you an option of "cloud services(classic)" because the web role is a concept used in Azure cloud services.

Web Role is a Cloud Service role in Azure that is configured and customized to run web applications developed on programming languages / technologies that are supported by (IIS).

For more information, you can refer to the links below.

- [what-is-web-and-worker-role-in-microsoft-azure](http://www.cloudmonix.com/blog/what-is-web-and-worker-role-in-microsoft-azure/)
- [difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941488/what-is-the-difference-between-an-azure-web-site-and-an-azure-web-role)